# Equation with k describing a circle

Tags: circles

My equation is the following, and I would like to find which $k$ can make it a circle.

$$x^2+y^2+4x-6y+k=0$$

My naive approach is to have $k$ to be $-4x+6y+c$ where c is any number, so that I can have any circle that is in 0. However k is a parameter and I can't really figure that out if I am missing something. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Complete the square on $x^2+4x$ and $y^2-6y$ separately.

Take all of the numbers, and the $k$, over to the right hand side.

You will have something like $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = t$, where $a$ and $b$ are numbers and $t$ is a mixture of numbers and the letter $k$.

You need $t > 0$ for a circle.

What range of values of $k$ ensures that $t>0$?

Answer (score 2):

Completing the square $$(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2=2^2+3^2-k$$

For real circle, $9+4-k\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+4x-6y+k&=0\\
x^2+4x+y^2-6y&=-k\\
x^2+4x+4+y^2-6y+9&=-k+4+9\\
(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2&=13-k
\end{align}
Compare with equation of the circle where its center on $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.
\begin{align}
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2
\end{align}
We get $r^2=13-k$. In order to make a circle, then $r>0$.
\begin{align}
r&>0\\
\sqrt{13-k}&>0\\
13-k&>0\\
k&<13.
\end{align}